# Using regular expressions to filter a given substring from a full string

Tags: regex

**Objective**

The goal is to extract the substrings `TEST_CASE` and `RESULT` from the string `| TEST_CASE  | RESULT   |` using regular expressions.

**A possible solution**

As an example `[^\s*|]` selects only the first character.

**Question**

What are examples of regular expressions that would extract the required substrings?

Comment: JavaScript? Java? C#?

Comment: I am revising all my past questions to make them useful to the community. I also added feedback below to the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this should do it: `/[^\s\|]+/g` and use the `g` global flag.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to repeat the character class one or more times like `[^\s|]+`

A negated character class matches not what you have listed in the character class and is kind of a broad match.

Another option is to be specific about what you do want to match. If you only want to match uppercase characters and an underscore, you could use `[A-Z_]+` or match 1+ times a word character `\w+`